# Injective function that is not surjective

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to find an example of a continuously differentiable function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ that is injective but not surjective.

I can easily find one from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ but I'm having difficulty finding one for the reals.

Comment: What's the one you have for the Integers?

Answer (score 34):

Hint: It might be easier than **exp**ected.

Comment: +2 for cleverness in delivery! Okay, I guess I can't do that. Well, +1, anyway.

Comment: That's a good one, +1.

Comment: He wanted a *fun*ction, not a *pun*ction ;)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen This thread's only big enough for one pun master--so you can just git out.

Comment: Punny, we are all so punny here.

Comment: It's kind of interesting that `** **` came out as italics + asterisks and not bold.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber: Yeah, it's strange. My guess is that the `**...**` notation for bold was invalidated because the closing `**` was followed immediately by letters, whereas the inner `*...*` notation for italics did not have that issue. To work around this in a question or an answer (but not in a comment), one can use the HTML-style notation: `easier than <b>exp</b>ected`.

Comment: @ruakh Thanks for the tip :)